# How to Remove Submitted Content from Search Engines (Google)?

Tags: seo, search-engine, sitemap

I have submitted 1000 pages to Google included in my sitemap, but I did it by mistake. I didn't want to submit all, I wanted to submit 800 and release 1 page per day during 200 days in order to add new fresh content every day, that way Google would see it as a frequently updated website which is a good SEO practice.

I don't want Google to know about the existence of those 200 pages right now, I want Google to think it is fresh content when I release it every day.

- Shall I resend the sitemap.xml with only 800 links and hide the pages in the website?
- If Google has already indexed the pages, is there any change to make Google "forget" those pages and not recognize them in the future when I release them back?
- Any suggestion about what to do?

Thank you guys.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Is there anything wrong about asking SEO questions? if it is, that is something I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do that. You're trying to cheat, Google doesn't like this. Remain your site as it is now, create new content and submit it into Google's index as frequently as you want. If you'll exclude previously submitted data from the index, with a high probability it won't be indexed again.

Comment: It is hard to say it is cheating since that is what I would do if I had to write the content by my own I would post daily, which is not the case because I already have all the content. Anyway that is what I will do once I run out of things that might work for me. Thank you very much.